# Cannot getText from list

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to getText but forever reason it is coming up empty.  The text is a readonly field called theater and then a list of 28 numbers underneath it.  I have tried many different ways of obtaining the text, including getAttribute which returns null.  I have a scroll down function that scrolls down the page so I can see that it is recognized by the selector as it is scrolling and counting.  I'm really lost on this one. I have an array called theaterArray that matches the text line by line, however cannot do this.

the html looks like this:

```html
<td class="capacity" title="Theater" data-style="theater">
  <input class="readonly" type="text" data-bind="value: capacityObservables.theater, readonly: $root.editItem() !== $data || enhanced, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" readonly="readonly">
</td>
```

what I have for my code:

```js
//I have tried using the data-bind but i get an invalid selector error

var theaterStyle = element.all(by.css('[data-style="theater"]'));

theaterStyle.count().then(function(count) {
  console.log(count);
  j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    //scrolls down the list element by element
    browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", theaterStyle.get(i).getWebElement());
    theaterStyle.get(i).getText().then(function(text) {
      console.log(text, theaterArray[j], j);
      expect(text).toEqual(theaterArray[j++]);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: @finspin there is a list of numbers which is viewable on the screen.  I just realized that the text value is stored in a 189 element array and is counting across rather then up and down.  so the elements I need to get the text of occurs every 7 elements the xpath for the first text I have to get looks like this: xpath=(//input[@type='text'])[22] I believe I need to write something to increment by 7 and it will grab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps text is stuffed in the value attribute. Did you try this,

```
element.all(by.css('td[title="Theater"]>input')).each(function(element, index) {
  element.getAttribute('value').then(function (text) {
    console.log(index, text);
    expect(theaterArray.includes(text)).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: that did it!!  however I have an array with an expect that checks line by line the values.  sticking that code inside my for loop is making everything print then entire list at once not one by one.

Comment: You have many options to compare expected text from an array to individual element text. One way is just checking whether array includes the text or not - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes Please check my updated answer

Comment: That doesn't work for me, After I read it in the first time I hit a filter button and it reads it sorts the number from least to greatest i then sort theaterArray and re readin theaterStyle element

Comment: not sure what exactly you mean. However this seems to be a different problem than the original. Can you elaborate more and update your question